# How do I make image view disappear from screen

Tags: iphone

I want to make image view disappear from screen.
I don't want to release it.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Steve has the same answer just different syntax. I have only ever used the syntax below.

```
myView.hidden = YES;
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple.

[myImageView setHidden:YES];

UIView documentation is here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html

From the docs:

> hidden
>
> A Boolean value that determines
>   whether the receiver is hidden.
>   @property(nonatomic, getter=isHidden)
>   BOOL hidden Discussion
>
> Setting the value of this property to
>   YES hides the receiver and setting it
>   to NO shows the receiver. The default
>   value is NO.
>
> A hidden view disappears visually from
>   its window and does not receive input
>   events. It remains in its superview’s
>   list of subviews, however, and
>   participates in autoresizing as usual.
>   Hiding a view with subviews has the
>   effect of hiding those subviews and
>   any view descendants they might have.
>   The hiding of subviews is handled
>   implicitly by the system and does not
>   cause the value in the hidden property
>   of those views to change.
>
> Hiding the view that is the window’s
>   current first responder causes the
>   view’s next valid key view to become
>   the new first responder.
>
> The value of this property reflects
>   the state of the receiver only and
>   does not account for the state of the
>   receiver’s ancestors in the view
>   hierarchy. Thus this property can be
>   NO but the receiver may still be
>   hidden if an ancestor is hidden.